# App crashes on launch time with react native CLI after installing react-navigation 5

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I have installed all the packages for `react-navigation`. I have followed all the instructions given from [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started).

After installation when I build the app it's building successfully but getting crashed after installing on emulator. I have also tried it on my phone. But every time it's getting crashed. Here is screenshot of my project [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jH0aw.png).

I also find out that it's  crashing only when i installed

(**#Installing dependencies into a bare React Native project**) this part of react navigation.

```
npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
```

Here are some others code of my project.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "KhulnaWheels",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.1.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.1.0",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^5.1.0",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.1.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.0.8",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.1.0",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^3.6.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

**android\app\build.gradle (dependencies section only)**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc02'
    implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0-alpha03'
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules


    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}
```

**index.js**

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';

import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Comment: add safearea context in root check this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-safe-area-context

Comment: check gesture handler android setup https://software-mansion.github.io/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: @ AshwithSaldanha  added safearea context in root. Also check gesture handler. not working. Same as before.

Comment: open android studio when app crashes it will give you why it crashed in logger

Answer (score 0):

Please run the below command

```
cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd ..
```